Wrong machine learning predictions at every run
I trained a machine learning model, and a few of the same rows (around 100 out of 1800) in my test set are giving wrong predictions at every run (10 times) with different seeds. Is there anything I should do about it e.g. throw it in the train set in exchange for some data from the train set to test set or leave it as it is?
Ran the model 10 times with a different seed. Got some rows getting wrong predictions consistently.

You should provide a minimal example of what you mean by wrong predictions. It is not clear if you get the same value for test and prediction data or not.
Also predictions are not wrong per se, you train a model and based on the quality of your data you will have an error when making predictions which will deviate from the test value by some amount.
Apologies for the general answer, but as I said, more context is required to better understand your problem.
